# Show search history in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic4

So I want to create a modal-like behavior for the search.

When the ion-searchbar is focused, a modal would slide from the bottom showing search history, which would hold the suggestion once the user starts typing. The problem with ionic nodals is the backdrop, I couldn't keep the ion-searchbar active to input search words.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This component is called Popover, you can create them pretty much like you do with a modal but using an `PopoverController` instead. The `PopoverController.create()` method has an `event` parameter that will tell which element will be the anchor for the popover, set that to your search bar and it should be magically aligned.

By default a backdrop is shown when the popover is created but it can be deactivated via `showBackdrop` property upon creation.

Take a look at the Ionic's [Popover API Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) for further information

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately, the Popover has the same issue as the Modal in my case.
You can only disable displaying the Backdrop, it will still be there, and I am not able the write in the searchbar while the popover is still active

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by using segments, as below:

```
    <div *ngIf="segment == 'prodSection'">
...
</div>
    <div *ngIf="segment == 'searchSection'">
...
</div>
```

I styled the two divs in a way to be on top of each other and added events to the searchbar like:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionFocus)="openSearch()" (ionCancel)="retProd()"></ion-searchbar>
```

And toggeled between the segments with setting the `segment` variable's value with each event.